# Category archive page isn't filtering by current category

Tags: categories

Ok all - this is bound to be ridiculously simple, as it's one of the most basic things you can do (https://craftcms.com/support/entries-related-to-category) - but I am ill and I can not figure out what I've done wrong.

I have a category group 'Things To Do'. That group is set to allow categories in it to have their own URLs. The URL format is: things-to-do/{slug} and it uses the template 'things-to-do/category'.

I also have a channel Things To Do, the URL format being 'things-to-do/{slug}' and using a different template 'things-to-do'.

If I go to the url for a category that exists, it loads the correct template and I can output the correct fields attached to the category itself; e.g., {{ category.title }} or {{ category.myCustomField }}

However, trying to output entries related to the category I'm viewing is instead just listing all entries regardless of their lack of association with the category...

```
{% set thingsToDo = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}
{% for thingToDo in thingsToDo %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

This should only be listing one entry for a given category, but it's listing all entries.

What have a screwed up?

Comment: Does it help if you're explicit about which section the entries should be from?

Comment: Nope, makes no difference, and the entries are in the same section anyway. This seems really odd.

Answer (score 2):

Mystery solved; the relation code was too general; some of the entries were related to the category *on the homepage*, and the example code doesn't care about how or where the entries are related to the category as long as they are somewhere somehow.

I needed to be more specific:

```
{% set thingsToDo = craft.entries.relatedTo({
    targetElement: category,
    field: 'typeOfThing'
}) %}
```

Works.